# WPF: Slider Thumb Outside the SliderControl

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I need to extend a slider thumb to stick out of its control. Is that possible then how? If not how can i achieve this? Please Help.

For e.g My slider's height is 50 but the thumb must start -50px outside the control and have 100 height.

[image]

Here yellow is the slider control, red is the thumb now I need the thumb to extend add the orange part to the same thumb.

Thanks

Comment: i think you need to change the template and possibly inherit from slider control and add a DP with an Extent Height property which you would bind to your thumbs height in your control template

Comment: That not an option i can't put my whole application inside a slide control. but thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

If you can build a UI using WPF controls, then you can define a new `ControlTemplate`... it really is no different. Here is how... always start by implementing the default `ControlTemplate` so that your object initially looks 'normal'. Then simply locate the part you want to change... and change it:

[image]

The trick with this one is that the `Thumb` does *not* stick out of the control, instead the whole control is enlarged. Now the default `ControlTemplate` is so large that I'm not going to add all of the XAML here. Start with the default one that @VimalCK kindly added a link to (don't forget to include the `Resources`) and then add these changes (hopefully I've remembered all that I changed:

```
    <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" StrokeThickness="1" Height="14" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            ...  <!--Use default XAML here-->
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Rectangle Height="200" Width="2" Stroke="Red" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then inside the `HorizontalSlider ControlTemplate`, change the `TrackBackground Border` definition to this:

```
<Border x:Name="TrackBackground" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
    CornerRadius="2" Height="4" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1">
    ...  <!--Use default XAML here-->
</Border>
```

Then use it with a `Height` like this:

```
<Slider Height="210" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

I think I documented all the changes that I made... if not, you might need to set a `Height`, or a `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom` on something... either way, just experiment until you get what you want. Exploring how the default `ControlTemplate`s have been defined is a great way to learn WPF.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. But the problem is i am using mvvm and prism the slider control in a container with other objects i would not be able to set the slider Height same as the height of the thumb. i need the thumb to look bigger then the slider control itself.

Comment: You'll need to look into the [`Adorner` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) then. I can't see any reason why you couldn't set the `Height` of the `Slider` to be bigger though, using `Grid.RowSpan`, `Panel.ZIndex` or `Margin`... you do know that controls can overlap, don't you? It's only that thin line that would go over the other controls.

Comment: The slider is inside the scrollview... thats why the thumb extending out side scroll view

Comment: So increase the size of the `ScrollViewer` then... the bit that would overlap other controls is invisible... it wouldn't get in the way.

Comment: The slider is inside a canvas with other controls,thats inside a scrollviewer -> Grid -> Usercontrol->grid->border->usercontrol->... so thats not an option :)

Comment: Well like I said earlier, you'll need to use an `Adorner` to that then. Good luck.

Comment: As far as i could find the content presenter inside the scrollview and another inside the usercontrol is clipping the thumb if i extend the margin and height of the thumb. is their are workaround to this?

Comment: Yes, you have two options which will display the `Slider` *on top* of the other controls: The first is simply to declare the `Slider` control *after* the others, eg. below it in the XAML; the second is to set the `Panel.ZIndex` attached property on the `Slider` to a high value.

Comment: Found the problem the problem is with the scrollview that contains the slider. ScrollContentPresenter of the scrollview is clipping the thumb. now how can i remove the ScrollContentPresenter from clipping?

Comment: There is a property called `ClipToBounds` which you can try setting to `False`, but that *is* the default value, so it might not help... apart from that, I'm afraid I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF controls provided by Microsoft has a default style and template which is available in MSDN and you can modify this based on your requirements. For Slider control Style and Template please visit below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know about style but the problem i am facing is how to make the thumb lager the the control it is contained in here it is slider control.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap thumb by Canvas Control and set ClipToBOunds= "False" like this

```
 <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
         <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
           Value="true" />
         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
           Value="true" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                     <Canvas>
                         <Border Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Top="-3" ClipToBounds="False" Background="Black" />
                     </Canvas>
                  </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
```